# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of expected SBM when cluster sizes are not equal.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

For the case we have an SBM model with two clusters of equal size (e.g. each of size n/2), we know that the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
J_{\frac{n}{2}} \cdot p & J_{\frac{n}{2}} \cdot q \newline
J_{\frac{n}{2}} \cdot q & J_{\frac{n}{2}} \cdot p
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is of rank 2 and its eigenvalues and eigenvectors are $\frac{n}{2} \cdot (p+q)$, $\frac{n}{2} \cdot (p-q)$ and $\vec{1}$, $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \end{bmatrix}$, respectively.

Is there any closed form solution for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the case where the clusters are not balanced, e.g. we have a matrix like this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
p & p & p & q & q \newline
p & p & p & q & q \newline
p & p & p & q & q \newline
q & q & q & p & p \newline
q & q & q & p & p \newline
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where this matrix is still of rank 2?

Comment: The [linked duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3431272) gives the answer, but note that it uses $p, q$ for the dimensions of the blocks and not for the entries.